# OP used very bad vulgar language in comment

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, offensive, comment-flags

Recently i saw one question is SO. Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989093/geocode-variable-gives-null-when-passed-into-onmaplongclick-android?noredirect=1#comment40699932_25989093.

And there are already many many solutions available for this type of questions so that I inform as a comment to OP that try to search on **Google** you'll get many solutions for that but after this he took this comment as negatively and he used some very bad vulgar language to me.

here is the screen shot I took

> [image: comment thread]

So this is not fair to used this type of vulgar language into Programming sites, so I really request to moderators please remove this OP's account. or any one has any solution to remove this comments.

Comment: Flag the comment as offensive and move on.

Comment: Deleting an account for a couple of comments is a bit much, isn't it? Just flag the comments and move on...

Comment: @Yannis ya that is fine but OP told me if you remove my account then i'll create a new one ...

Comment: @MD: and if they think we'll not notice then that's fine. The moderators are not *that* thick. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok i got it.thanx

Comment: related: [What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773) _"Some words, when present in a comment, make it eligible for **instant, automatic** one-flag deletion..."_

Comment: Wow, that guy really need an immediate spelling lesson!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just flag the comment as rude/offensive. Depending on the actual language used it may well get deleted automatically.

If it doesn't get automatically deleted, the moderators will see this and act accordingly.

Comment: given that there was [word f$ck](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa56k.png "screen shot") in the comment, it is most likely that [single flag would purge it automagically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238835/what-is-the-se-version-of-seven-dirty-words)