# Downvotes not being backed up or explained

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, post-ban, downvote-reason

I recently received a question ban, I am not trying to dispute this, the system works and I fully agree it has to be in place.

However a recent question ([Breaking if __name__ when a condition is not met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974221/breaking-if-name-when-a-condition-is-not-met)) received 3 downvotes, I am not disputing this either, I'm sure all 3 people who downvoted had valid reasons, one person did mention that I should add some code.

I later commented asking for why the downvotes were issued and also explained why I personally felt that my code wasn't relevant in this case, at no point was I defensive or demanding them to reverse the downvote, I just wanted to know why so I could improve my question.

Further to this, after issuing this comment (which received no replies) another downvote was issued, with no explanation.

One member commented saying that supplying some of my code would attract better answers, however I did receive a brilliant answer that politely explain where my logic was wrong and supplied a solution.

Just to summarise: I am not disputing the ban, or showing any disregard or disagreement for the system, I am in total agreement with that. But what should be done when a question is downvoted and very little explanation is given for it even when I specifically ask for some explanation. I would have loved to edit the question to help make it clearer, but I struggled to see what to do, ultimately leading to a question ban.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Require a comment explaining the reason for the first downvote on a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question) and of [Enable Optional Anonymous Reasons for Downvotes on Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253531/enable-optional-anonymous-reasons-for-downvotes-on-questions)

Comment: I wouldn't class it a duplicate of the first, I'm not saying that comments should be enforced, more asking what to do if no advice is given on how to improve a question but downvotes are still occurring. Should I delete the question? Ask for explanation like I did?

Comment: Deleted questions count towards a ban. It's much better to edit, if you can find a good way to do so. Now that it's on Meta, let's hope you will get some good suggestions here.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: Python is not something I know much about; then again, your original question (*sans* code) seems fair to me. It described what you are doing and why; and why it does not work. I would count downvoting *just because there are no codez* unjustified, here.

Comment: @Jongware After looking back at the question I can see why some people would see code as useful here! I was describing what didn't work, but just using words, some people may have found it clearer if they could see exactly how I was structuring my code. I've added code now and people seem to find the question far more agreeable now.

Comment: Note: you have comment "... I got the definition of loop wrong" - make sure to post minimal necessary code with exactly one problem - and that problem better be what you are asking about. "This person can't even write simple loop/assignment/if..., so this post can't be good" - is very possible reasons for downvotes ...

Comment: The problem with my understanding of a loop did cause the reason for asking the question. I was confused and therefore couldn't work it out, because I got the definition one. They are closely linked and not 2 completely separate problems. My misunderstanding caused the problem I was asking about.

Answer (score 9):

There is not a requirement (nor should there be) for anyone to explain their down-vote.

Yes, it can be frustrating - especially for answers - when it would be useful to know where you went wrong, but that's not the way Stack Exchange works.

Comment: I appreciate that down-vote explanation should be enforced or required, it would seem pointless. But as a new, low rep, member, asking potentially beginner questions, do you not think it'd be better to educate and ensure it doesn't happen again than to just downvote and move on? Again, not disputing the system, I'm talking on a level of user interaction. From a quality control measure downvoting without explanation is fine, but it certainly doesn't ensure quality of future questions.

Comment: @JoeSmart ideally that would happen, but enough new users fly off the handle when given constructive feedback that some users avoid doing it to avoid the arguments... for example, see the image in [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271949/op-used-very-bad-vulgar-language-in-comment) (not a perfect parallel, but the best quick example I could find)

Comment: @psubsee2003 it's a shame we can't trust new users to accept criticism and advice and understand that this site relies on quality and self-moderation of content...